# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'listen' - python сокет

Tags: python, сокет

Всех приветствую. Написал небольшой скрипт tcp сервера.

И почему-то выдает такую ошибку:

```
File "patch", line 9, in __init__
  self.__SocketServer__.listen(1) AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'listen'
```

Код:

```
class DataManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__port__ = 2121
        self.__ip__ = "127.0.0.1"
        self.__SocketServer__ = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.__SocketServer__ = self.__SocketServer__.bind((self.__ip__, self.__port__))
        self.__SocketServer__.listen(1)
        self.__log__("Waiting car connection...")
        self.__CarSocket__, addr = self.__SocketServer__.accept()
        self.__log__("Car socket connected")
        self.__CarSocket__ = None
```

Comment: Дак вот вся и суть в том, что там используется именно self.__SocketServer__, Скрин: https://imgur.com/a/qK4Tutd

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в этой строке

```
self.__SocketServer__ = self.__SocketServer__.bind((self.__ip__, self.__port__))
```

Метод `bind()` ничего не возвращает, поэтому `self.__SocketServer__` станет равен `None`. Исправьте на

```
self.__SocketServer__.bind((self.__ip__, self.__port__))
```